# Why does the address of an internal symbol needs to be recorded in .got?

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking, x86, dynamic-loading

I am reading the blog https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/11/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries-on-x64

In the part "x64 PIC with data references - an example", it seems that the module is telling the dynamic linker to fill the absolute address of `myglob` into `.got`, then the code get that address and read data from that address.

But why does the compiler have to do this, it's a symbol come from itself, why can't just use RIP-relative addressing to access this symbol? Is it because sometimes `.data` of the module might be load to a unknown offset to `.text`(instead of always loaded next to `.text`)?

I mean, if `address_of(myglob)-address_of(instruction_that_access_myglob)` is a certain value, why do we even have to know the absolute address of `myglob`?